# How much of the conversation needs to be sent?

Tags: visa, uk-visa

I am a british citizen and my wife is american- we wish to do a spouse visa soon. I know that for the spouse visa we need to show that we have been in contact and we have many different platforms which we have spoken on, on whatapp I have transferred the conversation to word and it says there are over 3000 pages worth of communication, obviously I can't send in all those pages.

Would it be okay to send 1 page per week since we started speaking- it goes back to the middle of 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar while I was applying for a visa and for us, it was just two months of chats and I could send in edited conversation from each day. In your case, a page a week should suffice since it proves contact over a period of time that is really long.

Also, just mention in your application that you are just including your chats from one day a week.

Comment: Thats brill, thanks for getting back to me. Hope yours went well when you did it.